# creating frequency table

Tags: chi-squared-test, contingency-tables, frequency

I have empirical data from what I am trying to produce frequency table. when I use table for showing frequency result is

```
 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 29 35
40 42 50 44 33 41 19 18 12 10  8  6  3  4  1  1  2  1  1  2  1  1
```

As you can see there is missing values (20,21 ...28, 30... 35)
I want to do chi square test to compare this data to generated random data set (gennegbin) that follow distribution(in my case negative binomial distribution).

1. How to do this,since chi square require same length frequency tables, or to use whole data sets to compare (I tried this and results is quite high p value)

Pearson's Chi-squared test

data:  amiladata and gennegbin
X-squared = 460.27, df = 529, p-value = 0.9858

2. should I make frequency count adding this missing values with frequency zero in my dataset and generated dataset.

Comment: What is your data? What does the `0, 1, ...` labels mean? What does it mean that you have no values? If you don't have them because you didn't observe them that they are possibly 0's. If you don't have them because they don't exist and never existed, then using 0's would be wrong.

Comment: First row is number of created files / day. Zero files is equaly possible number of "created" files durring a day. As you can see in my dataset there is no day with 20 files per day ( missing values in frequency). I know that I need to produce another column with expected values of frequencies in order to preform chi square test. My another approach is to generate random dataset that follow negative binomial distribution and then compare if those two datasets are from same distribution (again using chi square test) but still when I do this i get different numbers of files/ day at the end.

Comment: what I have done is observed all values higher then 17 like one bind (category) that s how I get same length of frequency table for empirical data and generated data. After that I have this result
X-squared = 24.961, df = 17, p-value = 0.09559. If my null hypothesis is that this data come from same distribution, is this proof ? When I look at x squared table it say if p = 0.05 for this degrees of freedom (17) then its critical value is 27.59 and if p = 0.10 it s 24.77